# Can I generate hashcode() and equals() with only one unique field?

Tags: java

Lets say, I have a class Student. Each student object has a unique field ( int ID ) plus other common fields (like String schoolName etc).

Now is it ok to generate hashcode() and equals() by considering ONLY the field ID ?

Comment: Why would it not be okay?

Comment: Yes. As long as you never want to compare two student instances with the same id and different other fields and have them come out as different.

Comment: Will there be any chance for two objects with different ID to generate same hashcode ?

Comment: The hashcode of an integer in Java is the integer itself, so if they have different ids, they will have different hashcodes.

Comment: Is it also conceptually right to implement in the above mentioned way ?@khelwood

Comment: There is a useful distinction between _value objects_ that have no concept of identity beyond the values of their field (e.g., there is no possible distinction between `Integer(1)` and `Integer(1)`) and _entities_, which have distinct identity (which is often represented as something like a database ID field). One design approach suggests that entities should _never_ override `equals`, because even two similar Students are not the same Student (if you want to check for sameness, check the ID specifically). If you _must_, then the ID field only is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely use ID for hashcode and equals. Based on the number of buckets in HashMap, multiple objects with different ID will share the same bucket and then the equals method will identify the right object. Since you are planning to use ID which is unique, equals method will compare the ID with each object in bucket -> LinkedList/Tree and identify the unique object.

**However there is a catch.** You can use ID in Hashcode if the ID is kind of an auto increment so that your objects are distributed evenly in the buckets. However if your ID field is some sort of pattern like 4, 8, 12, 16 etc., you will end up putting most of your objects in a portion of buckets. So in that case, use Hashcode to generate a prime number as prime numbers are best candidates for evenly distribution in Buckets.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the intent of your object and the intended audience.

1. Intent: There could be a case where a student gets married and changes their last name. Now if your code relies on .equals() to determine if there are changes to save then the changes won't get picked up to be saved. The same is true for any other field that may change on the Student object.
2. Audience: If you package your object into a library and give it to others. They may have an expectation that an instance of the Student object is equal if and only if all non-transient fields are equal.

Comment: Otherwise , is it fine ?

Comment: @SME I would not recommend it. IDs obtained from auto-incrementing fields in a database will naturally grow (starting from `1` or `0` and simply counting upwards). That means that your objects will never have a good hash distribution which will cause bad performance when used in hash-based collections such as `HashMap` or `HashSet`

Comment: But then .. How it affects . Because each ID value will generate a unique hashcode ? so how will the hash distribution  be affected ? @codeflush.dev

Comment: @codeflush.dev, hypothetically that could be solved by just having the hash as `id % 65000` or something like that, couldn't it?

Comment: @Taschi not with modulo, but by multiplying it using a prime, yes